# OpenXML put text in form field that has bookmark

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a word template that when opened has grey form fields to fill in, and each form field has a bookmark.

I can get the bookmark without a problem but I am having trouble adding text at that exact spot.
I have tried the following but the text is never inside the grey form field, either line before, line after, or same line but after the grey.

```
bookmark.Parent.Append(new Run(new Text("append"))));
bookmark.Parent.InsertAfterSelf(new Run(new Text("pafter")));
bookmark.Parent.InsertBeforeSelf(new Run(new Text("pbefore")));
bookmark.InsertAfterSelf(new Run(new Text("after")));
bookmark.InsertBeforeSelf(new Run(new Text("before")));
```

Anyone know how to properly do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you upload a sample document?

Comment: If the bookmark is not near a Run node, it can't work. You need to know where is the bookmark exactly. Use OpenXml Productivity Tool to show us what the XML look like.